# Import a file after the Jest environment has been torn down

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs

I'm making a simple API with Express and I'm trying to add tests with Jest but when I try to run the tests it displays the next error:

```
ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.

      at BufferList.Readable (node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:179:22)
      at BufferList.Duplex (node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js:67:12)
      at new BufferList (node_modules/bl/bl.js:33:16)
      at new MessageStream (node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:35:21)
      at new Connection (node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:52:28)
/home/jonathangomz/Documents/Node/Express/Devotionals/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:111
  var isDuplex = stream instanceof Duplex;
                        ^

TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
```

I'm not sure to trust the result if right after jest break (or something like that):
[image]

My test is:

```js
const app = require("../app");
const request = require("supertest");

describe("Testing root router", () => {
  test("Should test that true === true", async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const response = await request(app).get("/");
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
  });
});
```

My jest configuration on `package.json`:

```json
"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ]
  }
```

#### Notes:

I read about `jest.useFakeTimers()` but It's not working and I'm not sure if I'm using in the wrong way. I also tried adding it to the `beforeEach` method but nothing.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution? I've got the exact same issue than you.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 no :c it's a side project for learning so I pause the Testing part, sorry

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add the package to `transformIgnorePatterns` in the jest config.

Comment: where did you add it and what value did you use?

Comment: in `jest.config.js`. It depends on what package is causing the issue, here are the docs on it: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring

Answer (score -1):

By adding `jest.useFakeTimers()` just after all your import.

What about making your test `async` ?

```html
const app = require("../app");
const request = require("supertest");

describe("Testing root router",async () => {
  test("Should test that true === true", async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const response = await request(app).get("/");
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
  });
});
```

Comment: Test suite failed to run
Returning a Promise from "describe" is not supported. Tests must be defined synchronously.

Answer (score -1):

Add **jest.useFakeTimers('modern')** before the asynchronous call. Add **jest.runAllTimers()** after the asynchronous call. This will fast-forward timers for you.

```
const app = require("../app")
const request = require("supertest")

describe("Testing root router", () => {
  test("Should test that true === true", async () => {

    //Before asynchronous call
    jest.useFakeTimers("modern")

    const response = await request(app).get("/")

    //After asynchronous call
    jest.runAllTimers()

    expect(response.status).toBe(200)
  })
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding `--testTimeout=10000` flag when calling jest, it works for me.

Information based on [Testing NodeJs/Express API with Jest and Supertest](https://dev.to/nedsoft/testing-nodejs-express-api-with-jest-and-supertest-1km6)

> --testTimeout flag - This increases the default timeout of Jest which is 5000ms. This is important since the test runner needs to refresh the database before running the test

Comment: Has no effect on our case :(